# How to differentiate users in web application

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, web-applications, spring-security, database-connection

How to differentiate users, after they log in into their account, in the way that they cannot see and edit other users' data? Is it a good approach to remember somehow user id during logging procedure and then make queries like WHERE user_id=x? or is there any other smart way?

Basically, I am using spring framework for logging procedure, but I am not really advanced user of this framework. After user log in they have to insert some informations about themselves to the database (i.e. name, surname, e-mail etc) and fill in their timetables. I don't really know how to get id of current user to let them edit and insert only their own data.

Comment: Do you want to use Spring Security framework?

Comment: Get User object as explained by @Beshoy Samy. Get user_id using user.username from database. Later you can optimise this code by injecting user_id into custom User object directly (you need to prepare and setup UserDetailsService in this case). Or maybe user_id is already here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always get the current logged in user using SecurityContextHolder.
SecurityContextHolder has the logged in user for the current thread.

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
if (authentication != null && !authentication.getPrincipal().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("anonymous")) {
    User loggedInUser = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, you should store their user id in a session variable (if you don't know what sessions are look those up too)